# Corruption of heap when using delete []p;

Tags: c++, visual-c++

With I use delete []p, the corruption of heap will occur.

```
Rectangle *p[3];

for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
  p[i] = new Rectangle();

p[0]->set(3, 4); 
p[1]->set(10, 8); 
p[2]->set(5, 6); 

for(int i=0; i < 3; i++) 
    cout << "Area is " << p[i]->area() << endl; 

delete []p;
```

After I change delete [] to

```
for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    delete p[i];
```

It works but why I cannot use delete []p? Is delete []p only deletes p[0] and what [] means in delete []p?

Comment: Why are you using pointers in this example at all, instead of `Rectangle p[3]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`delete [] x` is for dynamically allocated arrays, not for arrays of pointers to dynamically allocated elements, which is what you have:

```
Rectangle* pA = new Rectalgle[3]; // dynamically allocated array
....
delete [] pA;  // OK

Rectangle* p[3]; // array of pointers. 
// Each pointer must be dealt with individually.
delete p[0]; // Might be OK, if p[0] points to dynamically allocated Rectangle.
```

Answer (score 9):

`delete []` is only to be used after an allocation with `new []`, and `delete` only after `new`.

This is how C++ works. If you want to simply allocate an array of 3 `Rectangle`'s, use this:

```
Rectangle *p = new Rectangle[3];

...

delete [] p;
```

Comment: Even in this case, you will still be required to `delete` individual `p`s.  Otherwise, you will have a memory leak.

Comment: @unxnut what if rectangle is a struct and doesn't contain any reference types?

Comment: @unxnut are you sure? I always thought you balanced new / delete and new[] / delete[]. Am I going to have to dust off my bounds checker and look at all my code?

Comment: @nightcracker the allocation of `p`s in the loop will have to be balanced by a `delete` for each of them.

Comment: @unxnut: sure, but the case I described is using `new[]`, not `new`. And the asker already figured out that he needs to use `delete` for each array member.

Answer (score -1):

p is an array of pointers, and when you only delete [] p, you are only deleting the array of pointers not  the objects that they are pointing to. So thats why you need to iterate through all the array, to delete the object created in each pointer. Same thing happens when using bidimensional dynamic arrays.

Comment: No. Why is everyone so confused here? p is a stack-allocated array of pointers. Don't try to delete that.